# Change 'From' field of magento contact form email to the sender

Tags: email, magento, contact-form

How would one go about changing the 'From' field of the contact form email to that of the sender's? For instance, if a customer was to fill in the form with the email 'test@test.com', how can I make the generated email be from 'test@test.com'?

I've looked at the 'email sender' field in the system admin panels, but this only allows for a range of preset store emails.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place where this gets sent is in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` at abouts line 100. It looks like the reply-to address for the emails is already set to the email address from the post, so if you're just looking to get easier replies, I'd suggest not fooling with it.

Another issue that you'll likely see is that sending email with a spoofed "from" address may cause your site to quickly become blacklisted from many email providers, which may affect the rest of your business.

That said, if you still want to do this, in that file change this code a bit:

```
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER), // change this
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Top quality answer - nothing annoys me more than spoofed 'from' emails!

Comment: Just to clarify, the email is sent to our admin, and setting the from address to the sender is required simply for our ticketing system. I'm not in the business of soliciting dodgy emails, I promise. That said, the code worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Geoff, from the perspective of email spam, there's no difference between the admin emails and transactional emails you send. Just a friendly word of warning, glad it worked.

Comment: So just to clarify –  having the reply-to-field set to the customers email is no problem spamwise? But spoofing the from-field could result in getting the server URL being blacklisted by the email providers (i e hotmail could blacklist incoming emails from that domain in the future)?

Answer (score 1):

[Magento Contact Form - been receiving email from myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811398) is a newer duplicate of this question and Joe's answer got me on the right path. In my answer to the duplicate question, I wrote a custom module to override `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` and ended up changing the indicated line above to `array('name'=>$post['name'], 'email'=>$post['email']),` to make the fix.

IMHO, when I do urgent small fixes in the core that have to stay until properly overloaded, I'm sure to end each line with a comment with my initials twice `//CKCK hack to fix ___` and then you can grep for this and see all of your mods via ssh shell: `app/code/core$ grep -rn "CKCK" *`

I'm also using github for version control, which helps, too.