# magento: change sender in order mails to customers email adress

Tags: magento

I'm refering to this post: [Change 'From' field of magento contact form email to the sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188855/change-from-field-of-magento-contact-form-email-to-the-sender/13159105#13159105)

how about the new order mail: If I change the code as indicated in the post above also the order confirmation mail that goes to the customer will get the 'spoofed' sender (would be in this case it's own mail adress) or only the mail for the admin (=shop owner) will recieve the order mail with the customers mail adress as sender?

the objective would be: 
new order mail to shop owner: sender = customers mail adress
new order mail to customer: sender = sales

the reason is, in outlook I can better search, sort and respond to a clients orders.

thank you Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` class and overwrite the `sendTransactional()` function. In this function you can swap the from email to the customer service mail.